# traefik ingress not forwarding tcp messages

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I am trying to aggregate raspberry pi logs (IoT Devices) into Logstash/ElasticSearch running in EKS.

`filebeat` is already running in EKS to aggregate container logs.

This is my manifest file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-config
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: logstash
data:
  logstash.conf: |-
    input {
      tcp {
        port => 5000
        type => syslog
      }
    }

    filter {
        grok {
            match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGLINE}"}
        }
    }

    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
        index => "syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }

---

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: logstash
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: logstash
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.2.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9200"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
          value: elastic
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: changeme
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
          value:
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
          value:
        ports:
        - name: logstash
          containerPort: 5000
          protocol: TCP
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 800Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
          readOnly: true
          subPath: logstash.conf
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: logstash-config

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logstash
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: logstash
spec:
  selector:
    app: logstash
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: tcp-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: logstash-external
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: logstash
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: tcp
spec:
  rules:
  - host: logstash.dev.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: logstash
          servicePort: 5000
```

able to send test message :

```
echo -n "test message" | nc logstash.dev.domain.com 5000
```

But don't see anything for `tcpdump port 5000` in logstash container.

If I run `echo -n "test message" | nc logstash.dev.domain.com 5000` from logstash container, then I see this message showing up for `tcpdump port 5000` on logstash container.

Within `EKS` from any container I can send test message `echo -n "test message 4" | nc -q 0 logstash 5000` and its received by `logstash` and pushed to `ElasticSearch`.

But not from outside of the cluster. So looks like `traefik` ingress controller is the issue here.

I have `traefik` ingress controller for EKS.

```
traefik.toml: |
  defaultEntryPoints = ["http","https"]
  logLevel = "INFO"
  [entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
      address = ":80"
      compress = true
      [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
      [entryPoints.http.whiteList]
      sourceRange = ["0.0.0.0/0""]
    [entryPoints.https]
      address = ":443"
      compress = true
      [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [entryPoints.https.whiteList]
      sourceRange = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    [entryPoints.tcp]
      address = ":5000"
      compress = true
```

and Service :

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-external
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  selector:
    app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
    - name: tcp-5000
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Have you check if there's any data in elasticsearch?

Comment: Filebeat is already pushing data to elastic search.

Comment: Can you verify that the logs from your raspberries reach logstash? Can you see the logs on the stdout?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used logstash before in the past then you may need to manually create a logstash index. The data won't appear under filebeat as elasticsearch isn't receiving the data from filebeat but logstash itself. I may be wrong in this answer altogether.
However, if you go to:

Settings > Index patterns > Create Index pattern
Then proceed to type in logstash where it asks for a name and select logstash from underneath like so:

[image]

After creating this you should then get a drop down on the Discover page that says logstash. Under the logstash drop down you should see all of the data you are pushing through

You may already have a logstash index setup and this may not be the issue at all

Comment: There is no index matching `logstash-*`. I think it's because data is not getting pushed to ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

The **hosts** setting in the elasticsearch output looks suspicious to me. As stated in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-hosts) one have to specify an URI there. You should specify the instance with the protocol like

> http(s)://{IP or name}:9200

like you do in your curl request.

I would give that a try.

Comment: Tried with `http://elasticsearch:9200`, still not messages in `logstash`